# How to trace event logs from provider "Microsoft-Windows-RPC" programmatically

Tags: winapi, window, rpc, etw, logman

I want to create a program that will trace event logs from the provider "Microsoft-Windows-RPC".

The program `logman.exe` by Microsoft is doing it like that:

```
logman start RPC_ONLY -p Microsoft-Windows-RPC -ets
```

When done, you can capture the logs like that:

```
tracerpt RPC_ONLY.etl -o RPC_ONLY.evtx -of EVTX
logman stop RPC_ONLY -ets
```

I want my program to be able to trace it like `logman` does but I didn't understand how.
Is there a function that I can "tell" windows that I want it to start tracing events related to `Microsoft-Windows-RPC`?

Comment: You can [Configure and Start a SystemTraceProvider Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/configuring-and-starting-a-systemtraceprovider-session). And `Wevtutil gp Microsoft-Windows-RPC` will show the level and keywords used to enable a manifest-based provider. [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/configuring-and-starting-a-systemtraceprovider-session)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Example that Creates a Session and Enables a Manifest-based or Classic Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/example-that-creates-a-session-and-enables-a-manifest-based-provider), I have traced `Microsoft-Windows-RPC` events successfully with some changes. With `log.etl`, you can then [Retrieve Event Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/using-tdhformatproperty-to-consume-event-data).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <wmistr.h>
#include <evntrace.h>

#define LOGFILE_PATH L"C:\\log.etl"
#define LOGSESSION_NAME L"My Event Trace Session"

// GUID that identifies your trace session.
// Remember to create your own session GUID.

// {AE44CB98-BD11-4069-8093-770EC9258A12}
//static const GUID SessionGuid = { 0xae44cb98, 0xbd11, 0x4069, { 0x80, 0x93, 0x77, 0xe, 0xc9, 0x25, 0x8a, 0x12 } };

// GUID that identifies the provider that you want
// to enable to your session.

// {D8909C24-5BE9-4502-98CA-AB7BDC24899D}
/*
name: Microsoft-Windows-RPC
guid: 6ad52b32-d609-4be9-ae07-ce8dae937e39
*/
static const GUID ProviderGuid =
{ 0x6ad52b32, 0xd609, 0x4be9, {0xae, 0x07, 0xce, 0x8d, 0xae, 0x93, 0x7e, 0x39 } };

void wmain(void)
{
    ULONG status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    TRACEHANDLE SessionHandle = 0;
    EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES* pSessionProperties = NULL;
    ULONG BufferSize = 0;
    BOOL TraceOn = TRUE;

    // Allocate memory for the session properties. The memory must
    // be large enough to include the log file name and session name,
    // which get appended to the end of the session properties structure.

    BufferSize = sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES) + sizeof(LOGFILE_PATH) + sizeof(LOGSESSION_NAME);
    pSessionProperties = (EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES*)malloc(BufferSize);
    if (NULL == pSessionProperties)
    {
        wprintf(L"Unable to allocate %d bytes for properties structure.\n", BufferSize);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Set the session properties. You only append the log file name
    // to the properties structure; the StartTrace function appends
    // the session name for you.

    ZeroMemory(pSessionProperties, BufferSize);
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.BufferSize = BufferSize;
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.Flags = WNODE_FLAG_TRACED_GUID;
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.ClientContext = 1; //QPC clock resolution
    //pSessionProperties->Wnode.Guid = SessionGuid;
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.Guid = {};
    pSessionProperties->LogFileMode = EVENT_TRACE_FILE_MODE_SEQUENTIAL;
    pSessionProperties->MaximumFileSize = 1;  // 1 MB
    pSessionProperties->LoggerNameOffset = sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES);
    pSessionProperties->LogFileNameOffset = sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES) + sizeof(LOGSESSION_NAME);
    StringCbCopy((LPWSTR)((char*)pSessionProperties + pSessionProperties->LogFileNameOffset), sizeof(LOGFILE_PATH), LOGFILE_PATH);

    // Create the trace session.

    status = StartTrace((PTRACEHANDLE)&SessionHandle, LOGSESSION_NAME, pSessionProperties);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
    {
        wprintf(L"StartTrace() failed with %lu\n", status);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Enable the providers that you want to log events to your session.

    status = EnableTraceEx2(
        SessionHandle,
        (LPCGUID)&ProviderGuid,
        EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_ENABLE_PROVIDER,
        TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        NULL
    );

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
    {
        wprintf(L"EnableTrace() failed with %lu\n", status);
        TraceOn = FALSE;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    wprintf(L"Run the provider application. Then hit any key to stop the session.\n");
    _getch();

cleanup:

    if (SessionHandle)
    {
        if (TraceOn)
        {
            status = EnableTraceEx2(
                SessionHandle,
                (LPCGUID)&ProviderGuid,
                EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_DISABLE_PROVIDER,
                TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                NULL
            );
        }

        status = ControlTrace(SessionHandle, LOGSESSION_NAME, pSessionProperties, EVENT_TRACE_CONTROL_STOP);

        if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
        {
            wprintf(L"ControlTrace(stop) failed with %lu\n", status);
        }
    }

    if (pSessionProperties)
    {
        free(pSessionProperties);
        pSessionProperties = NULL;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, it works :) 
Btw, is it possible to catch the events on my application instead of writing it to the file?

Comment: Yes. There is a [EVENT_TRACE_BUFFERING_MODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/logging-mode-constants) mode replacing *EVENT_TRACE_FILE_MODE_SEQUENTIAL*. It‘s a little tricky.

Comment: Great, thank you so much :) 
I am planning to do it in C# so it might be tricky to convert these functions.